# Is ”えんりょしなさい” correct

Tags: definitions, sentence

For this question, the correct answer is choice 2.
While I've already known the meaning of "いいかげんにしなさい" is "enough!" and "act properly!", I still have no idea about the reason that choice 1 is incorrect.

I looked up for some example sentences of "えんりょ"

As what I know, both "しなさい" and "ください" have nearly the same meanings.
(They just differ in the expressions and the strength of emotion.)

If "おタバコはご遠慮ください" is correct, then "おタバコはご遠慮しなさい" also seems to be correct for me.

Can anyone explain the usage of "遠慮" in details for me?

[image: correct answer:2]

Comment: `both "しなさい" and "ください" have nearly the same meanings. (They just differ in the expressions and the strength of emotion.)` -- 使える相手が違いますよね？「ください」はお客さんや目上の人に使えますけど、「しなさい」は部下とか子供とか目下の人にしか使いませんよね・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In adding to keithmaxx's answer, 遠慮する means "to refrain from doing by taking someone into consideration".

For example, when you are invited out to eat by your friend and the friend says that he will treat you, if you order many expensive cuisines,  you would be said ちょっと遠慮しろよ.

いいかげんにしなさい would be more natural in this case because the person who said that seems to just want him to stop doing a game.

Answer (score 2):

By ください the speaker is generally asking the listener for a favor.
しなさい on the other hand is more of a stern order.

In most Japanese situations this phrase is used to ask customers or audience to refrain from something. Unless you are in the position to be commanding others then you would be seeing

> （タバコ歩きは）ご遠慮ください。 Please refrain (from smoking while walking).

rather than

> もっと遠慮しなさい。 Hold back more (won't you).

as the speaker will more often use the humble form of speech (to hopefully elicit a favorable response).

Comment: Adding to your answer, I would like to emphasize the fact that since おタバコはご遠慮ください is written in a formal way with prefixes おand ご, it would be strange to write in the form of an order (しなさい). 遠慮しなさい is an expression that is common, e.g. mothers telling their children to restrain themselves, from a boss, or between friends etc. In neither of these cases would you say ご.

Answer (score 0):

I think Keithmaxx, bjorn and yuiichi tam’s answers’ are accurate.

In addition to that, the former sentence is “まだゲームをしているの？” which could imply you were already requested/advised to stop playing the video-game before. Therefore the correct answer in the book can be いいかげんにしなさい. which is more imperative than 遠慮しなさい。and more effective to notify that you are already beyond the limit.